# If $T$ is an orthogonally diagonalizable linear operator in an inner product space, show that $T^*$ is also orthogonally diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ is an inner product space and $T$ is a linear operator that is orthogonally diagonalizable. Show that $T^*$ is also orthogonally diagonalizable.

Here, $T^*$ denotes the adjoint operator. The reason I ask is that I am trying to think of linear algebra separately from matrix/vector operations as I was taught in undergrad. I'd like to know if it's possible to furnish a proof of the above statement **without the use of matrix/vector operations**.

I know how I would solve this in the matrix representation of $T$ (i.e. Let $A$ be the matrix representation, then we can write it as $A = PDP^*$ and then solve for $(A)^*$, etc...), but I'd like to understand how this can be solved more abstractly, using other properties of linear operators such as the dual basis.

Comment: I think the most robust, abstract proof here is to note that $$(PDP^*)^*=PD^*P^*$$ This follows completely from the property $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$, which holds for any definition of the adjoint.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But aren't the $PDP^*$ meant to be understood as matrices in such a representation? Or as the composition of linear operators? In which case, it could also be written $P \circ D \circ P^*$?

Comment: You could think of it as the composition of linear operators and the same rule applies (it is convention to drop the $\circ$ for the composition of linear transformations). The trick, if you want to do things that way, is to say what you mean by a "diagonal operator".